# How to compute integral curve on vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

In my lecture notes, there are two examples about integral curve, but there are no working out. So I just want to know how it be done.

Example1: $X={\partial \over \partial x}$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$, the integral curve through $(x_0,y_0)$ is $c(t)=(t+x_0,y_0)$.

**where $c(t)$ comes from ?**

Example2: $X=x^2 {\partial \over \partial x}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The integral curve $x(t)$ are solutions to the differential equation ${dx \over dt}=x^2$

**How to come up with this ODE?**

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Write down the definition of an integral curve of a vector field.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I think I get it now. For example 1, the ODEs are just ${dc^1 \over dx}=1$ and ${dc^2 \over dy} = 0$ where $c(t)=(c^1,c^2)$, am I correct ?

Comment: That's close, yes. But $c$ is a function of $t$, so it should be $\frac{dc^1}{dt} = 1,$ etc.  It's conventional (sigh) to write $c(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, so that in your second case, the equations become $\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = x(t)^2; \frac{dy}{dt}(t) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, @JohnHughes :) Small comment: The second one was on $\Bbb R$, so no $y(t)$ at all.

Comment: Good with math...not so good with reading. :(